# Opening subpage of CHM-Help C#

Tags: c#, chm

I want to open a specific subpage of my `CHM`-Help for my program.
I never did this in `c#`, so I need to know how to open the specific Page of the `CHM`.
A short example would be perfect.

Comment: "Subpage" doesn't mean anything in this context.  You can only open a specific *topic*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(Control, String, HelpNavigator)`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdbb0yt0.aspx)

```
// Open the Help file for the Character Map topic and 
// display the Index page.
private void Button2_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    Help.ShowHelp(TextBox1, "file://c:\\charmap.chm", 
        HelpNavigator.Index);
}
```

Comment: This worked for my program, but now I did another CHM, and when I open it from my other program, the topic I want is shown, but the tree at the left side is not opened, it looks like it was opene with no specific topic, and with 20 topic in some folders it's a problem. Any solution for this?